# Hiding frame after set amount of time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frameset

I have a page made up of 2 frames (not iframes).

How to achieve that: the top frame will disappear (or appear to disappear) by shrinking upwards after x seconds? As it disappears, I'd like for the second frame to move up so there is no top bar left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jQuery to do that with something along these lines

```
function hideFrame()
{
    $('#framename').slideUp(1000);
}
```

Then you could use a timeout function to call this:

```
setTimeout('hideFrame()', 5000); // Change 5000 to whatever you like in milliseconds...
```

And remember to change '#framename' to whatever yours is called like for an example:

```
<div id="framename">blah blah</div>
```

Hope this helps.

(Just noticed you put 'not iframes'...)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to utilize [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp), [.slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/), and [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).